# Fast way to turn Pandas DataFrame into nested list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas

Given a DataFrame like the following:

```
 col_a col_b col_c

0   0   1   a
1   0   2   b
2   0   3   c
3   1   4   d
4   1   5   e
5   1   6   f
6   2   7   g
7   2   8   h
8   2   9   i
```

I'm looking for a way to create a list of sublists, where each sublist contains pair-tuples for the `col_b` and `col_c` values corresponding to the `col_a` value. In this example, the required output is:

```
[[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')],
 [(4, 'd'), (5, 'e'), (6, 'f')],
 [(7, 'g'), (8, 'h'), (9, 'i')]]
```

i.e. the first sublist contains the three tuples where `col_a` is equal to `0`, and so on.

I managed to do it using a for loop like so:

```
main_list = []
for i in df["col_a"].unique():
    small_df = df.loc[df["col_a"] == i]
    sublist = small_df.drop(columns=["col_a"]).to_records(index=False).tolist()
    main_list.append(sublist)
```

But this solution is quite clunky and take an extremely long time to execute on a large df. I'm wondering if there is a faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby`:

```
totuple = lambda x: [(l, r) for l, r in zip(x['col_b'], x['col_c'])]
out = df.groupby('col_a')[['col_b', 'col_c']].apply(totuple).tolist()
print(out)

# Output
[[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')],
 [(4, 'd'), (5, 'e'), (6, 'f')],
 [(7, 'g'), (8, 'h'), (9, 'i')]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to approach the problem:

```
df['p'] = [*zip(df['col_b'], df['col_c'])]
l = df.groupby('col_a')['p'].agg(list).tolist()
```

---

```
print(l)

[[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')],
 [(4, 'd'), (5, 'e'), (6, 'f')],
 [(7, 'g'), (8, 'h'), (9, 'i')]]
```